# Multiple select val() returning null

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding items to a multiple select listbox which is working fine. However when I submit my form they are being returned as `null`. Strange thing is if I select the items before submitting they pass correct. I am confused as to why this is happening as form name and select names are correct and would appreciate some help in pointing out my error.

I have only posted the code where I am checking for value. Thanks

html

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="labelStyle" for="box_ni">Select Your Box(es)</label><br />
     <select id="box_ni" multiple name="box_ni[]" size="15">
      <option value="">
      </option>
    </select>
    <div id="nidstrmessage"></div>
    <div class="servicesHelp"><lead id="serviceHelp" class="form-text text-muted help">
      Read help <img src="/domain/admin/images/qmark.png" width="24px" height="24px" class="helpintk"/>
      </lead>
    </div>
    <div class="noBrtvBoxes" style="color:white;"></div>
  </div>
```

add code

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '#add', function() {
    var boxvalue = $("#box_input").val();
    if (boxvalue == '') {
      $("#niinputmessage").fadeIn(3000).html('No blank entries').fadeOut(5000).css({
        'color': 'red',
        'margin-left': '5px',
        'margin-top': '5px'
      });
      return false;
    }
    count = $('#box_ni').children('option').length;
    console.log(count);
    $("#counter").html("Total selected boxes for intake: " + '<span style="font-size: 14px; color: black;">' + '( ' + count + ' )' + '</span>').css('color:, black');
    if (count > 2) {
      $("#counter").html("No more than 3 items per intake. Please remove items from the list.");
      return false;
    } else {
      count++;
      $("#counter").html("Total selected boxes for intake: " + '<span style="font-size: 14px; color: black;">' + '( ' + count + ' )' + '</span>').css('color:, black');
    }
    $("#box_ni").append("<option>" + boxvalue + "</option>");
    $("#box_input").val('');
  });
});
```

js

```
$("#USRboxni").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var boxintake = $("#box_ni").val();
  console.log(boxintake); <-- RETURNS NULL
});
```

Comment: `.val()` on a multi-select does return an array: `https://jsfiddle.net/86wcznse/1/`.  Perhaps you could complete a [mcve] - specifically the complete and verifiable part - for starters your `select` has no options in the question.

Comment: Something to try: `console.log("#box_ni").length)` should == 1

Comment: @freedomn-m that is what I am getting returned: `1`.

Comment: But it is still returning 1 if there are 3 items in listbox.

Comment: The options are added from button click

Comment: My bad on the test, should be:  `console.log($("#box_ni").length)` - I guess you picked that up. That confirms there's only one `id='box_ni'` so it's not picking up an early textbox or something - it doesn't say how many options there are, that would be `console.log($("#box_ni options").length)` which will change as you add the options.  Can you update your question to show how you are adding the options, it might be relevant.  (cut-down version if it's complicated)

Comment: Aparently this is expected behaviour in jquery, This is documented at there github site. However, this begs the question how do I pass these values to submit function? Link here `https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2562`

Comment: @freedomn-m `console.log($("#box_ni options").length);` is displaying the correct count for options. Thanks

Comment: Did you read all of that issue?  It was fixed Nov 2015 - so which version of jquery are you using?  Works as expected using 3.3.1 (returns empty array both when no options present or no options selected) https://jsfiddle.net/86wcznse/6/

Comment: @freedomn-m added the code for item addition. I did read that but what is the point of having an empty array returned?

Comment: @freedomn-m 1.12.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue (as determined in the question comments) is that jquery 1.12.1 contains a bug/feature that will return null when no items selected:

```js
console.log($("select").val(), "== null", $("select").val() == null)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple></select>
```

this has been fixed in later versions of jquery (specifically tested with 3.3.1) (also failed in v2).

```js
console.log($("select").val(), "== null", $("select").val() == null)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple></select>
```

The work around for jquery<3 is to add `|| []` when retrieving the value:

```js
var v = $("select").val() || [];
console.log(v, "== null", v == null)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple></select>
```

Longer example using jquery 3.3.1: https://jsfiddle.net/86wcznse/7/

---

> what is the point of having an empty array returned

I believe the issue here is that OP is adding items, but *not selecting them*.

`$("select[multiple]").val()` will return the selected items, the addition to the question shows the items being added, but not being selected.

To get all the values of the items added, you can use `.map` :

```
$("select option").map(function(i, e) {
  return $(e).val();
}).toArray();
```

Example:

```js
var v = $("select option").map(function(i, e) {
  return $(e).val();
}).toArray();

console.log(v, "== null", v == null)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple>
<option value="1">one</option>
<option value="2">two</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I get that. But how do I get values from listbox if it is passing as an empty array? Thanks

Comment: I noticed that from your comment - you're not *selecting* the values, `.val()` will only give you the values you've selected.  You can extract the options themselves regardless of whether they're selected using `.map()` - I've updated the answer to show this.

Comment: You did mention this originally with "*Strange thing is if I select the items before submitting they pass correct*" - should have picked up on that earlier.

Comment: lol no problem. I can now see that the array is being populated correctly: `Array [ "ddd", "ddddddd" ]` but the serialize isn't getting the values. no box_ni in returned items from console.log(data). I just use `var data = $("#USRboxni").serialize();
  console.log(data);` to get values.

Comment: If you create submit input and try the serialize(); option you will the problem I still have to select to get the item values. Thanks

Comment: I shall close this question as solved and post a new question regarding serialize();. Many thanks for all your help and patience.